# Create the Sierpinski Pyramid with a L-system

Tags: recursion, processing, fractals, l-systems

The [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L-system) for L-Systems describes many of them, including a couple rules that converge toward the Sierpinski triangle. That particular fractal also [has a 3D version](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/2/29/Sierpinski_pyramid.jpg), which basically uses pyramids instead of triangles. Is there a way to reach this one with an L-system? That same wikipedia page mentions the existence of 3D L-systems, but doesn't explain how they work or give any example as to what their rules would look like.

So first, how do 3D L-systems differ from their 2D counterpart (if there are major differences), and second, can they be used to create this Sierpinski Pyramids?

I'm trying to create it in Processing, as I managed to draw the 2D version in this software using an L-system before. An example of making a 3D L-system work would be appreciated, but not necessary

Comment: @SethDifley, sorry, I've edited the question

Answer (score 0):

A 2D L system in instructions for creating recursive 2D trees with branches that contain number of sub-branches, angle, and length. A 3D version expends the branches to have roll, pitch and yaw. Its easiest to create one with turtle graphics. (If you just use a orthographic projection, you can see the tree, which is of course flattened again to 2D, but looks more complex and less symmetrical than a 2D tree)

Otherwise the system is the same.

I don't know the instruction sequence specifically for creating a Seipinsky pyramid. Presumably you stat at the apex pointing down, then do a  pitch of 45*,
and four Rolls with 4 As between them.